# Refresh only one parameter of list item in recycler view item contains increment + decrement + spinner

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I want to refresh only one parameter of list item where list item contains provision to increase or decrease the value and spinner.

When I select the spinner value and increase and refresh item by notify datachange() the value of spinner goes on default each time I increase or decrease.

How to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the solution.
i just take one Boolean isFirstTimeInflate = true;
in adapter when it is first time inflate all the views.
when item position == list.size();
make isFirstTimeInflate = false;

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Category category = categories.get(position);

        holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ActionEvent(category, position, true, false));
            }
        });

        holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ActionEvent(category, position, false, true));
            }
        });

        if (isFirstTimeInflate) {
            value.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(context, R.layout.points_spinner_row, category.getAvailableCards()));
            value.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    category.setValue(category.getAvailableCards().get(position));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }

        count.setText(category.getCount() + "");
        if (position == categories.size()-1) {
            isFirstTimeInflate = false;
        }
    }
```